# Porting MSVC code to Gcc, alternative to _wfopen() on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, visual-c++, gcc, porting

I'm porting Windows MSVC code to Linux gcc.

`_wfopen()` seems to be a MSVC specific function to open file with name constructed of `wchar_t` `(UTF-8)`.

Is there an alternative for `_wfopen()` on Linux? 
Is there an alternative which could be used both on Windows and Linux for `UTF-8`?
What is the best way to solve this problem instead of putting OS specific `#ifdefs`?

Comment: UTF8 doesn't need wide characters. Use `fopen`.

Comment: `_wfopen( fullFileNAme.c_str(), L"rb");`
needs to be replaced. Can't use `fopen()`.

Comment: "name constructed of wchar_t (UTF-8)" You are mistaken - `wchar_t` is not UTF-8. It's UTF-16 on Windows, UTF-32 on Linux. `wchar_t` is nearly impossible to use in a portable fashion. Further, Linux handles file names encoded in UTF-8 and represented by sequences of `char`, while Windows wants its file names in UTF-16 and `wchar_t`. To make your code portable, you'll likely need to implement some kind of platform abstraction layer to deal with file names - or use a third-party one, e.g. [boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html)